# Converting Multiple rows into columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have two tables:

**TableA**

```
+-------+--------+
| Data  | Acc_No |
+-------+--------+
| Unix  |     10 |
| Linux |     20 |
+-------+--------+
```

**TableB**

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| Obj | Type     | Amount |
+-----+----------+--------+
|  10 | rev      | 100.00 |
|  10 | revision | 200.00 |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

I want the output like this

```
 +-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
 | Data  | Acc_No | Type     | Amount | Type_1    | Amount_1 |
 +-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
 | Unix  | 10     | rev      | 100    | revision  | 200      |
 +-------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I tried doing it using a simple join. Here is the query:

```
SELECT a.Data,a.Acc_No, b.Type, b.Amount, bb.Type AS "Type_1", bb.Amount AS "Amount_1"
FROM TableA a,TableB b, TableB bb
WHERE a.Acc_No = b.Obj AND
      b.Obj = bb.Obj AND
      bb.Obj = a.Acc_No AND
      a.Acc_No =10;
```

But I got this output.

```
+------+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
| Data | Acc_No | Type     | Amount | Type_1   | Amount_1 |
+------+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
| Unix |     10 | rev      | 100.00 | rev      |   100.00 |
| Unix |     10 | revision | 200.00 | rev      |   100.00 |
| Unix |     10 | rev      | 100.00 | revision |   200.00 |
| Unix |     10 | revision | 200.00 | revision |   200.00 |
+------+--------+----------+--------+----------+----------+
```

I tried searching for the answer in this site and I even googled it but I didn't find the right answer to it.

Comment: Will the two types always be `rev` and `revision`? Will there be other types? Will there be more than two types?

Comment: No there are only two types, rev and revision. It is just a sample data but my higher up is expecting this kind of output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current query is close but I'd suggest a few minor changes to it to get the result.  If you want to "pivot" the data using JOINs, then you'll need to distinguish between which value you want to return from `TableB` in each subsequent join.

For example, when you want to return `type=rev`, you need to include a specific filter for that value.  Then you'll do the same thing with `type=revision`.  I'd also suggest using a `LEFT JOIN` to join to `TableB` in the event you don't have both `type` values for each `Acc_no` then you'll still return data.

```
select
  a.data,
  a.acc_no,
  b.type,
  b.amount,
  bb.type as type_1,
  bb.amount as amount_1
from tablea a
left join tableb b
  on a.acc_no = b.obj
  and b.type = 'rev'
left join tableb bb
  on a.acc_no = bb.obj
  and bb.type = 'revision';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ef5/2)

You could also get this result using some conditional aggregation, then you don't have to join to `TableB` multiple times:

```
select
  a.data,
  a.acc_no,
  max(case when b.type = 'rev' then b.type end) as type,
  max(case when b.type = 'rev' then b.Amount end) as Amount,
  max(case when b.type = 'revision' then b.type end) as type_1,
  max(case when b.type = 'revision' then b.Amount end) as Amount_1
from tablea a
left join tableb b
  on a.acc_no = b.obj
group by a.data, a.acc_no
order by a.acc_no;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ef5/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort but I want the exact output as I have shown in the expected output. Do you think creating a view and displaying its contents would work?

Comment: @Am1t What do you mean you want the exact output that you showed? This gives the exact output except I didn't filter for `acc_no = 10`.  As to your 2nd question, you could place this in a view.

Comment: I want only those data which is related to `Acc_No=10` but when I execute the above query I get Linux which has an `Acc_No = 20`. So filtering should be done based on `Acc_No= 10`.

Comment: @Am1t All you need to do is include a WHERE clause see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48ef5/6

Comment: ♦ Oh yes, That did the trick.Thanks a lot. Im very greatful to you.

Comment: @Am1t You are welcome, you asked a great first question.  Provided everything that was needed to give a solution! And even included the query that you tried.